# Strange behaviour,it may be an attack

Tags: users, security

I have a political [website](http://sahara-question.com/en), and I expect attacks anytime. Yesterday, someone told me on my Facebook page that he will hacker me; I blocked him immediately.

Today, when I tried to create a user on the site, I noticed that a default username was used every time I tried creating a new user account.

What can I do to fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suspect it may be your browsers cookies. try with a different browser. I tried creating a new user on your site. seems fine to me.

Comment: Yes it's from the Cookies,But isn't that an attack?

Comment: unless you mean cookies are bad for your health, then no. its normal. Dont worry about it.

Comment: You could vote up my comment if you like my answer ;)

Comment: it's a comment not an answer,how to vote up a comment?

Comment: Comments can be voted. That is why the first two comments have a "2" before them.